# How to check if month change?

Tags: laravel

I want to update all my depriciation cost each month for all items until 0

Example.

```
Depriciation has value of 111 . each month it should be depreciated until depriciation cost 
reach 0 or less than
```

[image]

***controller***

`all_item=assets::all();`

```
foreach($all_item as $item)
{
     //should i make static month to compare?

     $month=Carbon::now()->format('m');

     $update_item = assets::findOrFail($item->id);
     $update_item->depriciation_cost = $item->depriciation - $item->depriciation_cost;
     $update_item->update();
}
```

Comment: You should create a function that updates the data each month.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column in the table to keep track of the last depreciation value updated like `depreciation_updated_at` (type: date) OR use `created_at/updated_at` column to get the last update month (if no other reason to update record).

Then simply use updated version of your code:

```
all_item=assets::all();

foreach($all_item as $item)
{
   $month=Carbon::now()->format('m');
   $depreciation_updated_at = createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $item->depreciation_updated_at); //or can use created_at/updated_at as said below
   if ($depreciation_updated_at ->format('m') != $month) {
      $update_item = assets::findOrFail($item->id);
      $update_item->depriciation_cost = $item->depriciation - $item->depriciation_cost;
      $update_item->update();
   }
}
```

Hope it will do your task.